# Fast redrawing of image in MATLAB using Image.CData

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure

I am want to draw once, and then update (very) often and redraw (less) often an image in MATLAB. My image is a vector which is updated and redrawn. To show this image, I used `I = imagesc(reshape(data, nVoxels))` to draw and `I.CData(:) = data` to update. (Redrawing is taken care of seperately.) This worked fine.

Now, in order to make the correspondence to an x-y-coordinate system (x horizontal, y vertical - very standard), where the first dimension of `reshape(data, nVoxels)` is x and the second is y, I need to draw like this:

```
I = imagesc(reshape(data, nVoxels)');
axis('xy');
```

But how can I make a quick update of the image data now?

So far, I have found I need to do

```
I.CData = reshape(data, nVoxels)';
```

but I would prefer to do something like before, updating CData without having to reallocate and without having to transpose the data.

Is that possible? I am specifically interested in updating very often in a loop; redrawing is handled independently using a timer.

Comment: changing I.CData does redraw (if CData is changed, that is). Here's an example: `nVoxels = [3 5]; data = rand(nVoxels); I = imagesc(reshape(data, nVoxels)); pause(1); data = rand(nVoxels); I.CData(:) = data;`

Answer (score 1):

The transpose can be avoided by setting x and y limits when you create the image to flip it, and rotating the axes:

```
I = imagesc([nVoxels(2) 1], [1 nVoxels(1)], reshape(data, nVoxels));
camroll(90);
```

then using

```
I.CData(:) = data;
```

again.

However, the transpose time is probably negligible compared to updating the figure using `drawnow()`.

Comment: I.CData(:) = data; only redraws the figure if the MATLAB process becomes idle. Otherwise you need to call drawnow() to explicitly update the display.

Comment: As the OP, I can say this is no problem for my case (it's actually what I want) - I want to update often and redraw only when I need to. I will update my question accordingly in a bit.

Comment: As to the answer itself: Your `I = imagesc([nVoxels(2) 1], [nVoxels(1) 1], reshape(data, nVoxels));` line does not show the image in the same orientation as my `I = imagesc(reshape(data, nVoxels)');` line (because the transpose is missing). Your idea of setting decreasing limits would be helpful if I had to flip the image data - but it cannot help in getting rid of the tranpose operation.

Comment: This is not a bad idea at all. But it not only rotates the image, but the whole `axes` with all children, so that any annotation etc. will be affected, too (see the manual: "`camroll` sets the axes `CameraUpVector` property and also sets the `CameraUpVectorMode` property to `manual`."). So in maintaining the relation between the image and the axes, it does not achieve what I achieve by using the transpose operation. But this brings me to another idea which I might suggest in an answer.

Comment: (I was thinking about using the MATLAB `rotate` function to display a rotated image. But that's not going to work, since this functions operates on the `image`'s `xdata` and `ydata`, which determine only the boundaries of the image, not the orientiation or locations of single pixels.)